# How to find the size of dynamic array

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

Is there any way I could find how much bytes are allocated for `RandomArray` in this code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

    int main()
    {
    int *RandomArray;
    int n;
    srand(time(NULL));

    RandomArray=malloc(sizeof *RandomArray * (rand()%11));
    printf("%d  %d",sizeof(RandomArray),sizeof(*RandomArray));

    return 0;
    }
```

Also I don't know whether above code will ever have any kind of practical usage. But I am looking from programming perspective.

Comment: nope.. need to keep track of that yourself.

Comment: And you don't save the result of `rand()%11` and validate it is greater than zero, because...?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin well, `malloc(0)` is not illegal.

Comment: It's also not very useful...

Comment: @ely I looked to close this as a dup, but that Q isn't a direct dup. While you are certainly correct that the explanation there should suffice, that Q is more about the inability to use `sizeof` if an array has decayed to a pointer or you are using a pointer to array. It doesn't directly cover the case where you lack the foresight to save what you allocate.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin not, but the OP is not using the memory anyway, the OP wants to know the size.

Comment: Yes, got that, the whole problem here is if you don't save the size you allocate, there is no magic wand to wave to get it back.... It's one of those "smack yourself in the forehead" type issues.

Comment: `sizeof(RandomArray)` is the size of the pointer.  It is not the size of the allocation.  `sizeof(*RandomArray)` is the size of an `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah this is experimental code. Interesting things are there.

- You will allocate memory for `N` integers where `N` is between `0` to `10` including `0` and `10`.
- Then you applied `sizeof` to the pointer (`int*`) and what it points to (`int`). It won't matter how much memory you allocate. The output from this line will be same.
- There is no error check here. if it was you couldn't tell whether it is successful entirely surely because `rand()` may give `0` as result. You need to store it somewhere and check whether it is `0` because on that case `malloc` may or may not return `NULL`.
- Printing what `sizeof` returns should be done using `%zu` format specifier. It returns `size_t`.

> - To be more clear remember it is a pointer pointing to dynamically allocated memory. `RandomArray` is not an array - it is an pointer pointing to contiguous memory. That doesn't make it array. It is still a pointer. And the `sizeof` trick that you wanted to apply thinking `RandomArray` is an array won't work. In general we keep track of it - using some variable. But here you don't know how much memory you allocated.

- `malloc` may return `NULL` when you pass `0` to it. Handle that case separately. In case you get `sz!=0` and get `NULL` in `RandomArray` throw error.

  ```
    size_t sz = rand()%11;
    RandomArray = malloc(sz);
    if(!RandomArray && sz){
       perror("malloc");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  ```

After all this talk - the short answer is, with this setup *there is no use of the code (code you have written) so far*. You don't know what `rand()` returned on that case inside malloc.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, by saving the size in a variable:

```
int main()
{
    int *RandomArray;
    int n;
    srand(time(NULL));

    size_t size = rand() % 11;
    if(size == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Size 0, no point in allocating memory\n");
        return 1;
    }

    RandomArray = malloc(size * sizeof *RandomArray)
    if(RandomArray == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "no memory left\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("%zu  %zu\n", sizeof(RandomArray), size);

    // don't forget to free the memory
    free(RandomArray);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that `sizeof(RandomArray)` returns you the size that a pointer to `int`
needs to be stored in memory, and `sizeof(*RandomArray)` returns you the size of
an `int`.

Also don't forget to free the memory.

Answer (score 3):

Since the expression `*RandomArray` is of type `int`, `sizeof(*RandomArray)` evaluates to `sizeof(int)`.  It does not tell you how much memory was allocated.

When dynamically allocating memory, you need to keep track of how much was allocated yourself.  In the case above, you would need to store the random number someplace so you know what that amount is.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(RandomArray)` always results in 4 bytes(equal to pointer size), if you want to find how many bytes allocated for `RandomArray`

```
/* Since its implimentation dependent, so I'm not 
  advising you to access RandomArray[-1], also proper type casting needed */
printf("memory allocated = %d \n",RandomArray[-1]);
```

From

> The C programming language by Denis Ritchie & Kernighan

```
 typedef long Align;    /* for alignment to long boundary */
   union header {         /* block header */
       struct {
           union header *ptr; /* next block if on free list */
           unsigned size;     /* size of this block */
       } s;
       Align x;           /* force alignment of blocks */
   };
   typedef union header Header;
```

The `Align` field is never used;**it just forces each header to be aligned on a worst-case boundary**. 
In    `malloc`,the requested size in characters is rounded up to the proper number of *header-sized* units; the block that will be allocated contains
one more unit, for the `header` itself, and this is the value recorded in the
`size` field of the header.
**The pointer returned by malloc points at the free space, not at the header itself**.

```
              RandomArray[-1]                      
   -----------------------------------------
   |        |     SIZE     |               |
   -----------------------------------------
                                          RandomArray

        -> a block returned by malloc
```

Comment: Is there anything in the standard that guarantees that `malloc` saves the size before pointer is returning? I don't think you can relay on that.

Comment: But isn't that just an implementation detail? Do all `malloc` implementation do that as well?

Comment: If the requested memory cannot be allocated, a null pointer is
returned. If the size of the space requested is zero, the behaviour is implementation-defined: either a null pointer is returned.

Comment: While this answer does provide useful information about a common implementation detail, it unfortunately is _an implementation detail_, i.e. absolutely _**not guaranteed to work that way**_. Further, indexing `RandomArray[-1]` is almost guaranteed to fail — you’ll need a much more sophisticated cast than that to do it correctly.

Comment: That is only an example of a storage allocator (from K&R Example 8.7); the Standard does not mandate such a header. In any case, I'm not sure what you would gain with this knowledge. It would be undefined behavior to attempt the access `RandomArray[-1]`, and undefined behavior to even form the pointer `RandomArray - 1`.

Comment: agree @DavidBowling about UB.

Comment: @Dúthomhas yes `RandomArray[-1]` need to be typecasted.

Answer (score 0):

The `sizeof` operator works at **compile time**, except for the case when the operand is variable length array, and the dynamic memory allocation is **run time** operation.
In the expression:

```
printf("%d  %d",sizeof(RandomArray),sizeof(*RandomArray));
```

the type of `RandomArray` is `int *` and the type of `*RandomArray` is `int`.

Hence, the expression is equivalent to:

```
printf("%d  %d",sizeof(int *),sizeof(int));
```

for which the `sizeof` will yield the result as an integer constant and therefore, you will get the same result every time irrespective of the size of memory allocate to `RandomArray`.

> `How to find the size of dynamic array`

**Keep the track of the *size*** from the point where you are allocating memory dynamically.

---

Beware, you are multiplying the value returned by `rand()%11` to the `sizeof *RandomArray` while allocating memory and `rand()` may return `0` as well which will lead to `malloc(0)`. Good to know that (from [C Standards#7.22.3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3)):

> ....If the size of the space requested is zero, the behavior is implementation-defined: either a null pointer is returned, or the behavior is as if the size were some nonzero value, except that the returned pointer shall not be used to access an object.